# Use AngularJS on Sharepoint Online 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, angularjs

I'm a computer science student and I realized in my last sandwich training,
the company i work on use SharePoint Online and I must create a custom application for the company. This application will be a form.

So i think i will use AngularJS to create it. I have never used this framework, so I think this project is a good occasion to learn it.

I want to know what you think is better, only put a script on SharePoint or put a full Angular application.

Thanks very much, see you !

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know what you think is better, only put a script on
>   SharePoint or put a full Angular application.

The whole point of being a student is to answer this yourself.

So do not take any answer for granted, weigh them and make up your own mind

It is like learning to play with Lego, you learn it brick by brick

- first spend a day entering values in a SharePoint Tasks list and see what the EditForm is and does.
- Then leave SharePoint and spend a day playing with Angular in JSFiddle or CodePen
- If you want to compare Frameworks, do the same with React
  Frameworks are like fashion, what was hip yesterday is old-fashioned today,
  The foundation of all Frameworks is plain vanilla JavaScript, that is the language you need to learn first.
  Once you master JavaScript (and don't forget the new ES6 syntax) you can work with any Framework
  Frameworks are like the pre-packaged stuff you buy in the supermarket; they help you get results fast, but it all depends on what you need to do.
- Now you know your Lego bricks and how they fit together it is time to do the real work...
  Note: Like me, most programmers in real life can't do this phase, that's why we are Programmers and not IT-Architects
  You take a blank sheet and a pencil and you draw your application;
  **Why is Which Lego brick needed and How will they fit together?**

If you still want to play with Frameworks you now start programming yourself

In the real world the IT-Architect hands over the drawings to builders,
and sends and invoice for an insane amount to the customer

Comment: This. All to often devs coming into the SP world don't understand the application. Understand what SP can do ootb, and then use frameworks to fill gaps. Don't rewrite the entire application.

Comment: **and** the other way around.. SharePoint DEVs now venture into the Front-End world with SPFx; thinking they are up to par with real Fronteers because they learned to spell HypeScript and now can cook pasta from a package. And it is not only Lego, technology or pasta.. I learned, the hard way, it applies to (relationships with) women as well ****

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use and learn new frontend framework, I think you should try [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) or [Angular 2](https://angular.io/), because they are most poplar now. For example, Microsoft uses React to create their own components for modern pages. There are ready to use [Office UI Fabric components for React](https://dev.office.com/fabric) created by Microsoft.

Whether you should use Script Editor Web Part or App Part with SharePoint-hosted Add-in/Provider-hosted Add-in depends only on your requirements. Script Editor is the easiest way to embed custom JavaScript application on SharePoint, because iFrame is not used and you don't have to take cross-domain requests into consideration. But this has several disadvantages too. When you use App Part application is running in iFrame in app web context (SharePoint-hosted) or another web application context (Provider-hosted), which can cause some difficulties for inexperienced developers.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is a full fledged client MVC framework and you can use it along SPO to develop an Angular form application, that way you wont have to worry about hosting your form on any individual server